# wordpress php code not running (wpforms)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm hosting a local wordpress site through xampp, and am testing some code. Basically I wanted to take the form data from a wpforms, and when the user clicks submit it then sends that data to an external mysql database. This is the code

```
global $wpdb;
function be_db_connector($fields) {
$username = 'example';
$password = 'example';
$database = 'example';
$localhost = 'example';
$wpdb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->insert('ProspectsDevOnly', array(
    'username' => $fields['0']['value'],
    'password' => $fields['2']['value'],
    'email' => $fields['1']['value'],
    'create_time' => 20180526),
     array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%d',

    ) );
}
add_action( 'wpforms_process_complete_7', 'be_db_connector', 10, 1 );
```

I put the code in my themes function.php file, but when I submit the form nothing happens - nothing is sent to my database.

Any idea why this may be? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > First you can enable debug mode in wp-config.php in root folder.
> >
> > Assign value for username,password,database,password.

```
 function be_db_connector() {
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'root123';
    $database = 'account';
    $localhost = '127.0.0.1';
    //$wpdb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
    $wpdb = new wpdb($username,$password,$database,'localhost');

    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $insert = $wpdb->insert('account', array(
        'firstname' => '',
        'lastname' => '',
        'age' => '',
        'gender' => 20180526,
        'emailad' => '', 
        'username' => '',
        'password' =>''
         ));
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'be_db_connector', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: thank you, your comment hellped a lot. it turns out when i was passing the variables while making the $wpdb I did not use the variables i had already assigned ('username' instead of $username). it works perfectly now.

Comment: quick question, is there a method to get the date so it returns it in a format like '20180614' ?

Comment: you can get >> get_the_date('Ymd');